# Expected number of coin toss to get two consecutive tails with maximum of six trials

Tags: probability, expected-value

We toss a fair coin for a maximum of six times. During this process,
if we obtain two consecutive “tails”, we stop tossing the coin. What
is the expected number of coin tosses?
I know that if we can have an infinite many trials the expected number of tosses would be:
TT = 1/4
HTT = 1/8
HHTT, THTT = 1/8
HHHTT, HTHTT, THHTT = 3/32
HHHHTT, HTHHTT, HHTHTT, THHHTT, THTHTT = 5/64

So the expected number coin tosses is:
2*(1/4)+3*(1/8)+4*(1/8)+5*(3/32)+6*(5/64) = 2.3125
Is this way correct?

Comment: No, because the maximum possible is $6$ and the minimum possible is $2$.  Probably easiest to work recursively, if the first toss is $H$ you restart with one fewer toss available.  If $TT$ the answer is $2$.  If $TH$ you restart with two fewer tosses available.  $6$ is small enough so you could just write it all out, but I think a little recursive work makes it a whole lot easier.

Comment: So I need to least out all the possibility of getting two consecutive tails from 2 to 6 toses? Are there any different ways to do this?

Comment: I already said, work recursively.  That's very easy.  Suppose you had only $2$ tosses, then the answer is obviously $2$.  What if you had three tosses?  Four?  the recursion is simple, and you should see that the terms grow asymptotically towards $6$.

Comment: Your posting is missing several details.
Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).  With respect to *showing work*, which is only one of the details missing from your question, you have the option of letting the comments of lulu guide you along a direction to research.

Comment: Note: You are to stop at 6 tosses *whether* the last two were consecutive tails *or not*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your (second editted) way is correct, but do note: Because it is the maximum allowed, you must stop at 6 tosses *whether* the last two were consecutive tails *or not*.

- 2 tosses (TT) = $1/4$
- 3 tosses (HTT) = $1/8$
- 4 tosses (HHTT, THTT) = $2/16$
- 5 tosses (HHHTT, HTHTT, THHTT) = $3/32$
- 6 tosses (anything else) = $1-(3+4+4+8)/32 = 13/32$